Short logcat on Android 13+
I'm seeing a small number of logcat entries from my apps and the system, since Android 13, and now Android 14, on both my Pixel 6 Pro and Pixel 8 Pro.
I can only see entries from about 5 - 10 minutes into the past before plugging the phone in to check the logcat. If I leave it plugged in, then it doesn't clear and I can see as far back as I could when I first plugged it in. However, a lot of the time I need to check something a couple of hours after it happens while the phone was unplugged.
I have increased the log buffer size in Developer Options to 4M and then 8M and it's still the same. I should be able to see logcat entries from the previous day with such big log buffers! It's also the same whether checking the logcat from Android Studio or from the phone itself with a logcat reader app, unless I leave it open to record.
Has anyone else run into this? Anything I can do to bring this back to how it was on Android 12 and below?
